# How to use the * when using symbolic link within tcl script

Tags: linux, tcl, tcsh

So I'm kinda new to the Linux env and I'm learning to use .tcl script. I want to use symbolic link to link a bunch of files in multiple folders with similar end word (for example: abc123.rpt). Normally in the Terminal I can easily do this with:

```
ln -sf ./dir/*/abc*.rpt
```

But I want to use this usage in my .tcl script, and if I understand, using exec like this:

```
exec ln -sf ./dir/*/abc*.rpt
```

Will do the cmd outside of the script env I'm using and exec cmd in terminal env (which is tcsh). It's ok when I use for 1 file only, but it don't understand when using this cmd with * and the files linked back is literally "abc*.rpt"

Comment: You can make symbolic links within Tcl directly with the `file link` command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform a file name globbing to achieve the desidered result:

```
exec ln -sf {*}[glob ./dir/*/abc*.rpt]
```

Source: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm#M29

Bye

Comment: Thks very much for your answer.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, as suggested by @Donal Fellows consider using `file link` command. Going natively is always a more efficent solution, there's no need to spawn a new child process. Bye.